# Delete unassigned shards in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I had an elasticsearch server, which ran in single node mode.
When dataset reached 1TB, I added second node and relocated couple of shards with reroute api.
Now second node has 2 of 5 shards, but first node still holds all 5 shards and space is not reclaimed.

**_cat/shards?v** command shows:

```
new_messages                    3     p      STARTED    974698739 256.6gb 5.188.130.61  el01
new_messages                    3     r      UNASSIGNED
```

I've found some "solutions" like stop ES and delete files by hand, but I don't like them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the solution is to delete shards with replica status.

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/myindex/_settings?pretty=1" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' {"index" : { "number_of_replicas": 0 } }'
```